# Import / use SHA1 passwords on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, md5, sha, password-encryption

I've just built a new Wordpress website and I'm trying to import my members from a previous website to the new one. The import was successful, except now all logins fail. My old website used SHA1 hash to encrypt passwords, whereas Wordpress uses MD5. Is it possible to convert all my SHA1 passwords to MD5 and keep the same passwords?

When the website goes live I want all my previous members to be able to login with the same passwords as before (seamless as possible).

Comment: Neither SHA-1 nor MD5 are appropriate to store passwords. They are ways too fast and can be brute-forced too easily (about 100Giga MD5 per second). It is high time to switch to a safer algorithm like BCrypt. See also https://roots.io/improving-wordpress-password-security/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert sha1 pass to md5. Moreover wordpress use a salt to create it's hash.

You have 2 solutions:
The easy one: send a mailing to all users asking them for changing their password

The hard one: change wordpress auth mecanism.

Comment: I've prompted all users to reset their password which has done the trick...many thanks for your advice!